# divide and conquer assignment

Tags: java, quicksort

I have to write a java program to simulate a robot to match lids with it's corresponding jar. The robot has two arms, one for the lids and one for the jars.  I can't compare lids with lids or jars with jars. The user will enter three lines:

```
5(n)
9 7 2 5 6(size of lids)
2 6 5 7 9(size of jars)
```

The output should be:

```
3 5 4 2 1
```

The 3rd number in line 2 is equal to the 1st number in line 3 and so on.

We are supposed to use a divide and conquer algorithm and I really have no idea where to start.  All I have to go by is it's similar to quicksort.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm)

Comment: 1. Write some code -- any code, just to get going; compile it; if it doesn't compile, investigate. 2. Once it compiles, test it.  If the tests fail, repeat #1.  If you have code that isn't working, post it and we'll help you out.  There's not much we can do, however, if you don't make an effort to get going on your own.

Comment: I would start by creating the data structures you need, make your 2 lid and jar arrays and an output array.

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer algorithms might be confusing at first.  Think about it as if you have some relatively large problem that you can't solve, but if that problem was much, much smaller you could find the answer.  Applying it to this situation: suppose instead of having 2 big lists of lid and jar sizes, you instead have 1 lid size and some number of jar sizes.  You could easily tell me which jar that lid fits on, right?  The idea of solving the problem for 1 lid is essentially breaking the large problem (several lids) into a smaller one (1 lid).  Once that makes sense, you can move on the algorithm.

You will likely employ some recursion in order to write your algorithm.  Start with the base case and solve the simplest meaningful problem (I like the 1 lid example).  Once you can solve that problem, can you recursively solve the same problem for every lid?  I'm not attaching any code because I don't want to spoil the learning experience for you (and this is clearly homework).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of "divide and conquer" is to divide up the work into multiple, smaller problems; then you solve the smaller problems and roll them up until they are combined into a solution.  This pretty much implies a recursive solution.

With any recursive function, you always need a "basis case".  This will be a simple case that is trivially easy to solve.  For example, if you only have one jar and one lid, then you simply return that the jar matches the lid.  (Because as part of the problem statement, you always have one matching lid for each jar.)

So one place to start is a trivial program that only works right for a length-1 list of jars/lids.  Then add more machinery to make it more capable.

With quicksort, you choose a place to divide up the numbers (the "pivot"), then do a very rough sort (just take numbers that should be on the left of the pivot but are on the right and move them to the left, and vice versa).  Then you call quicksort recursively on the sublist.  Eventually each of the recursive calls to quicksort hits a basis case (a length-1 sublist); once they all have hit the basis case the quicksort is done.  (Note: there are ways to optimize quicksort and make it faster by adding more code, but I'm talking about the simplest implementation of quicksort here.)

Maybe in this case you should start with a length-n list of just the numbers from 1 to n, and and then swap the numbers around until you have a correct list?

Hmm.  With length-2 lists, there are only two possibilities: the lists line up, or not.  If they line up you are done.  If not, you swap the numbers to make them line up, and you are done.  Hmm.  This is similar to sorting in a way, but you can't just compare numbers directly like you can when you are sorting.  (In sorting you always know that 3 sorts below 5, but here it might not be so.)  So, now think about a way to break down the list and keep doing it until you have a length-2 or length-1 sublist, then handle those trivial cases.

Sounds like a fun problem.  I hope you enjoy working on it.